# Welches neutrale Verb gibt es für "kacken", das kein Euphemismus ist?

Tags: single-word-request, euphemism

Zu gegebenem Anlaß heute morgen fiel mir auf, dass es im Deutschen anscheinend kein Verb gibt für das, was jeder morgens auf dem Topf macht, das nicht entweder vulgärsprachlich (V) oder ein Euphemismus (E) wäre. Auf Anhieb fallen mir ein

- kacken (V)
- scheißen (V)
- Stuhlgang haben (E, oder zumindestens aus einem E entstanden)
- koten (das ist jetzt wirklich kein gebräuchliches Verb, würde aber am ehesten noch meinen Ansprüchen genügen. Online-Duden meint allerdings, es ginge nur für Tiere)
- Seine Notdurft verrichten (E)
- sein (großes) Geschäft verrichten (E)

Für "das andere" kennen wir *urinieren* oder *Wasser lassen* (oder ist das auch ein Euphemismus?), und das ist beides auch einigermaßen gebräuchlich. Das Englische kennt das Verb "to defecate", das einfach sagt, was man macht, ohne auf Vulgärsprache oder einen Euphemismus (dafür aber immerhin ein Fremdwort) zurückzugreifen. Kann es sein, dass es für eine so häufige Tätigkeit im Deutschen kein passendes Verb gibt? (Wenn ich mir's recht überlege, ist das im Spanischen oder Französischen wohl genauso)

Extrapunkte für eine Erklärung, warum sich die Sprache anscheinend so sehr darum zu drücken (sic) scheint.

Comment: Klar gibt's welche, aber die klingen dann halt schnell medizinisch (stuhlen, koten, defäkieren). Am neutralsten vielleicht noch "den Darm entleeren" (oder ist das schon euphemistisch?)

Comment: @Ingmar - So isses. Anscheinend "rutscht" jedes Verb, sobald es einigermaßen gängig wird, ins Vulgäre ab, oder es bleibt ein medizinischer Fachbegriff.

Comment: Da der Vorgang vulgär ist und tabuisiert, ist jeder Begriff dafür, der nicht vulgär ist, qua definitionem ein Euphemismus. Nicht die Sprache drückt sich, sondern die Sprecher. Apropos drücken ... - ich geh' mir mal kurz die Nase pudern.

Comment: Das ursprüngliche Wort dafür ist das etymologisch sehr interessante Wort *scheißen*, das leider ganz in die Vulgärsprache abgeglitten ist. Es ist verwandt mit einer Vielzahl anderer Wörter. Aus der Wurzel *»skeit«* sind gewachsen: *scheiden, die Scheide, die Scheidung, das Scheit, der Scheitel,* sogar *der Schädel,* aber auch *gescheit* und *scheitern* und eben auch *die Scheiße, der Scheiß* und *scheißen*.

Comment: Zum *Koten* gibt's immerhin den Spruch "Nach dem Koten wasch die Pfoten!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na, da gibt es noch außer den bereit in der Frage genannten Verben und nicht der medizinischen Fachsprache angehörig:

> abführen
>   sich entleeren

Und ein eben verhüllendes:

> sich erleichtern (E)

Dass die gängigen Wörter nun der Vulgärsprache angehören ist ein Phänom, dass mehr mit der beschriebenen Tatsache zu tun hat als mit dem Wort. Also die vulgäre Verwendung kam erst später. So schreiben die [Grimms zu scheiszen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS06368#XGS06368):

> das jetzt durchaus gemiedene wort erscheint in älterer zeit, die es z. theil, wie die belege zeigen, ganz unbefangen braucht, häufiger in der schriftsprache,

Answer (score 8):

Ich würde sagen, das ist [defäkieren](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/defaekieren).

Comment: Um mit einem Romanzitat zu antworten: "Ich weiß, was das Wort bedeutet. Aber ein Typ in einem Witz würde *scheißen* sagen, oder meinetwegen auch *Geschäft machen*, aber bestimmt nicht *defäkieren" (*Ein Mann der Tat*, Richard Russo). Das würde ich nichtmal beim Arzt sagen.

Answer (score 4):

Da "Stuhl(gang)" ein auch unter Medizinern üblicher Begriff für die festen Hinterlassenschaften ist, würde ich "Stuhlgang haben" noch in den Raum werfen.
Meine erste Idee beim Lesen der Frage war auch "koten", aber das habe ich tatsächlich noch nie im Zusammenhang mit Menschen gehört sondern nur in der Tierwelt. Beides ist aber mMn durchaus neutral konnotiert und auch kein Euphemismus.

Comment: Ich befürchte, dass das wahrscheinlich auch ein Euphemismus ist, den wir nur nicht mehr als solchen wahrnehmen, bin mir aber natürlich nicht sicher. Der Vorgang an sich hat mit einem Stuhl nicht notwendigerweise was zu tun.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn *Wasser lassen* noch kein Euphemismus wäre, würde *Kot absetzen* sicherlich durchgehen.

Comment: Wenn *urinieren* neutral ist, wäre vielleicht auch *koten* halbwegs neutral?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das habe ich in meiner Frage schon genannt, und das ist wohl sicher neutral. Bloß gebräuchlich nicht (oder sagst du das beim Arzt?). Der Online-Duden meint, das sei auch nur für Tiere zu gebrauchen.

Comment: Ich nicht, warum alle Vorschläge als "nicht gebräuchlich" wegkritisiert werden. In der Frage wird nicht gesagt, dass das gesuchte Wort auch irgendwie "gebräuchlich" sein muss und das es jemand beim Arztbesuch benutzt. Wenn ein gebräuchliches Wort für einen Arztbesuch gesucht wird, davon wurde in der Frage selbst schon genug genannt, und dann ist die ganze Diskussion überflüssig.

Comment: tofro  - Stimmt, da habe ich die Frage nicht gründlich gelesen, du hattest das da eh schon erwähnt.

Answer (score 0):

Ich plädiere klar für das Wort:

> koten

Es ist die Analogie zu *urinieren* und im Gegensatz zu *defäkieren* leichter verständlich. Die Festlegung auf den tierischen Kontext halte ich persönlich für antiquiert und falsch und den Menschen überhöhend über andere Lebewesen. M.E. gibt es keine geeigneterte Alternative, da das Thema halt tabuisiert wird und immer die Flucht in die Euphemisierung gesucht wird.

PS: Ggf. auch überlegenswert: der Geschlechtsakt

Comment: Funfakt: Von Nichtkreationisten wird der Mensch heute unumwunden als Tier kategorisiert.

Answer (score 0):

Ich möchte an dieser Stelle kurz auf die Frage der Tabuisierung eingehen. Das Problem ist einfach der natürliche Ekelfaktor, der vor allen Dingen ein Schutzmechanismus ist. Dazu ein Auszug aus [Planet Wissen](https://www.planet-wissen.de/gesellschaft/psychologie/emotionen_wegweiser_durchs_leben/pwieekelwennabneigungextremwird100.html):

"Ein nahezu weltweit gemeinsamer Nenner sind jedoch Kot, Urin und Eiter sowie Leichen und der Anblick oder Geruch von verdorbenen Lebensmitteln. Eine Ekelreaktion soll das Infektionsrisiko senken und im Extremfall durch den Brechreflex dafür sorgen, möglicherweise oder tatsächlich verdorbenes oder giftiges Essen schnell aus dem Körper zu befördern."

Um Ekelreaktionen in der gesellschaftlichen Kommunikation möglichst zu minimieren, wird zu Umschreibungen (Euphemismen) gegriffen. Interessant ist dabei wirklich, wie gut der menschliche Geist durch dieses oberflächliche Kaschieren quasi verarscht werden kann, während doch immer klar bleibt, was wirklich gemeint ist.

Answer (score 0):

*exkrementieren*: Feiner Ausdruck für kacken, scheißen, abkoten, einen Kaktus drehen, eine Wurst machen, Aa machen. Verballhornung von "exkretieren".

> Bitte entschuldigen Sie mich einen Moment. Ich muss mal kurz exkrementieren.